# Filter a custom product loop to get products from a category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have this function which calls me all products type "promotion_package" in WooCommerce:

```
<?php foreach ( (array) $products as $product ):

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'promotion_package' ) || ! $product->is_purchasable() || $product->get_duration() <= 0 ) {
        continue;
    }

endforeach; ?>
```

I would like to get only products from "vip" product category.

I tried using `$product->get_categories()` to find "vip" category, but it didn't worked.

How can I show only products from "vip" category?

Comment: This is all the code
<?php foreach ( (array) $products as $product ):

       if ( ! $product->is_type( 'promotion_package' ) || ! $product->is_purchasable() || $product->get_duration() <= 0 ) {

        continue;

       }

       ?>                
      <?php endforeach ?>

Comment: I need to make sure that only type promotion_package, category VIP products are displayed.
I tried $ product-> get_categories () but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `has_term()` conditional function for `'product_cat'` procuct category taxonomy  as follows:

```
<?php 
    $categories = array('vip'); // Your categories (can be terms Ids, slugs or names)

    foreach ( (array) $products as $product ):

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'promotion_package' ) || ! $product->is_purchasable() || $product->get_duration() <= 0 
    || ! has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    endforeach; 
?>
```

It should work,

Comment: Forgive me. I'm new around here!
It is not working
promotion_package is a type product. not product category

Comment: The category is "vip"